# outputting unexpected "None" value when using self.list in oop python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, oop, output

I have a parental class employee and inheritant classes developer and manager.I used a for loop in print_emp
method in manager class and the "None" is outputted when I run the man_1.print_emp() method:

```
#parent class
class employee:

    raise_amount=1.05

    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
        self.first=first
        self.last=last
        self.pay=pay
        self.email=first+'.'+last+'@gmail.com'
        '''above are all attribute'''

    def fullname(self):
        return f"{self.first} {self.last}."

    def apply_raise(self):
        self.pay=int(self.pay)*self.raise_amount
class developer(employee):

    raise_amount=1.10

    def __init__(self,first,last,pay,prog_lang):
        super().__init__(first,last,pay)##just  like employee.__init__(self,first,last,pay)
        self.prog_lang=prog_lang

class manager(employee):

    def __init__(self,first,last,pay,emp_list=None):
        super().__init__(first,last,pay)##just  like employee.__init__(self,first,last,pay)
        if emp_list is None:
            self.emp_list = []
        else:
            self.emp_list = emp_list
         
    
    def add_emp(self,emp):
        if emp not in self.emp_list:
            self.emp_list.append(emp)

    def remove_emp(self,emp):
        if emp in self.emp_list:
            self.emp_list.remove(emp)

    def print_emp(self):
        for emp in self.emp_list:
            print(f"--> {emp.fullname()}")

emp_1 = employee('aung','khant',2000)
dev_1 = developer('test','name',1000,'python')

man_1=manager('man','ger',3000,[emp_1])
man_1.add_emp(dev_1)
print(man_1.print_emp())
print(man_1.email)
```

The output contain "None" like that:

```
--> aung khant.
--> test name.
None
man.ger@gmail.com
```

How do that "None" is outputted?Please help.

Answer (score 0):

The method `print_emp` of the class `manager` return `None`.
Therefore the call:

```
print(man_1.print_emp())
```

prints `None`

I think that

```
man_1.print_emp()
```

is what you are looking for.

Comment: print(man_1.print_emp()) give output:  --> aung khant \n --> test name and extra "None"

Comment: As I explained ,the extra `None` is the return value of the function call.

Comment: Not return just "None" but also -->aung khant and  --> test name

Comment: Lets add a new line to the function  print_emp(). Add the line `print('^^^^^^^^')` as the last line of this function. You will see it in the output before the `None`

Comment: I checked that function for a few times and I still couldn't catch the error why ```None``` is returned by my function call. Please

Comment: There is no error. A python function which has no `return` is just return `None`. This is what you are facing.

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it